# How to list the capabilities associated with a process in *nix systems?

Tags: linux, process, selinux, linux-kernel, containers

From - `man capabilities`

> UNIX implementations distinguish two categories of processes:
> privileged processes (whose effective user ID is 0, referred to as
> superuser or root), and unprivileged processes (whose effective UID is nonzero).

and

> Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux divides the privileges traditionally
> associated with superuser into distinct units, known as capabilities,
> which  can be independently enabled and disabled.  Capabilities are a
> per-thread attribute.

**Does any Linux command or technique exist to determine the capabilities associated with a running process (or thread).**

Comment: a little related post - [How to find out what linux capabilities a process requires to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469038/how-to-find-out-what-linux-capabilities-a-process-requires-to-work)

Answer (score 2):

The utility `getpcaps` will show the capabilities for a given PID.

From the man page:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> getpcaps pid...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> getpcaps  displays  the  capabilities on the processes indicated by the
> pid value(s) given on the commandline. The capabilities  are  displayed
> in the cap_from_text(3) format.

Comment: `ps` - output 
    `PID TTY          TIME CMD
  25777 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
  25811 pts/1    00:00:00 vi
  25839 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
` and then

Comment: `sudo getpcaps 25777` output 
`25777: =`

Comment: same with - `sudo getpcaps 25811` output 
`25811: = `

Comment: why are the capabilities empty - does it really mean there are no capabilities associated with these two processes

Comment: after `su -`, when i did the same for bash, `sudo getpcaps 25876` output
`25876: =ep`. what is `=ep`

Comment: That's what it really means. Most processes won't have any capabilities associated with them.

Comment: Those are the flags, as documented in the cap_from_text man page which the answer referred you to. This process appears to have all capabilities granted to it.

Comment: any thing wrong with this - `man 3 cap_from_text` output
`No manual entry for cap_from_text in section 3`

Comment: @samshers You don't have the package installed that provides that man page (it's in the -dev package).

Comment: could you please give the full package name, so i can apt install

Comment: `libcap2-dev` ??  no such package.

Comment: @samshers You didn't mention your Linux distribution?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 :-))

Comment: @samshers Aha. Despite the base package being named `libcap2` the dev package is `libcap-dev`, no 2.